# mdk3 error installition

Tags: apt, package-management, make

tried many times and many ways install mdk3,
without success
thanks for those who helped !

**~/mdk3-6.0$ sudo make install**

/tmp/cc9h6CjX.o: In function `init_channel_hopper':
/home/jenanie/mdk3-6.0/mdk3.c:1269: undefined reference to`pthread_create'
/tmp/cc9h6CjX.o: In function `ssid_brute':
/home/jenanie/mdk3-6.0/mdk3.c:2282: undefined reference to`pthread_create'
/tmp/cc9h6CjX.o: In function `ssid_brute_real':
/home/jenanie/mdk3-6.0/mdk3.c:2332: undefined reference to`pthread_create'
/tmp/cc9h6CjX.o: In function `intelligent_auth_dos':
/home/jenanie/mdk3-6.0/mdk3.c:2702: undefined reference to`pthread_create'
/tmp/cc9h6CjX.o: In function `wids_machine':
/home/jenanie/mdk3-6.0/mdk3.c:2790: undefined reference to`pthread_create'
/tmp/cc9h6CjX.o:/home/jenanie/mdk3-6.0/mdk3.c:2868: more undefined references to `pthread_create' follow
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:22: recipe for target 'mdk3' failed
make: *** [mdk3] Error 1

Answer (score 0):

mdk3 can be installed in Ubuntu 17.10 and later from the default Ubuntu repositories. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install mdk3
```

In earlier versions of Ubuntu manually download either [mdk3_6.0-4_amd64.deb](https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/amd64/mdk3/download) or [mdk3_6.0-4_i386.deb](https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/i386/mdk3/download) depending on your OS's architecture. Open a terminal, use `cd` to change directories to the directory where mdk3_6.0-4_amd64.deb is located and install it using these commands:

```
sudo apt install aircrack-ng
sudo dpkg -i mdk3_6.0-4_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is always good to understand an error and to not rely on packaging for everything. To install **mdk3** from the source you just need to slightly modify the second line of the makefile. 
The makefile as it comes starts like this:

```
CFLAGS        = -g -O3 -Wall -Wextra
LINKFLAGS    = -lpthread
```

And you can see in the error log that the compiler searches for `pthread` and not for `lpthread`. So, you just have to edit the second line of your makefile and remove the **l** in the the value `-lpthread`. Like this:

```
CFLAGS        = -g -O3 -Wall -Wextra
LINKFLAGS    = -pthread
```

Save the modification. You can now compile correctly and install **mdk3-v6** in your Ubuntu with `make` and `sudo make install`

[image]